# Bootstrap Affix ( bottom class )

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, affix

hello all i have a bootstrap Affix , The broblem is the #sideBarContainer is take the rop class perfect , and when i scroll the class change to Affix perfect too , but when i arrive to the point that i need it to stop and change the class to bottom-affix , not stop :( why ??

```js
$('#sideBarContainer').affix({
  offset: {
    top: 100,
    bottom: 200,

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sideBarContainer">
  <div class="ReadHeaderSections">
    <p></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

From the docs:

> If a bottom offset is defined, scrolling past that should replace
>   .affix with .affix-bottom. Since offsets are optional, setting one
>   requires you to set the appropriate CSS. In this case, add position:
>   absolute; when necessary. The plugin uses the data attribute or
>   JavaScript option to determine where to position the element from
>   there.

CSS (or Less):

```
.affix-bottom {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: u didnt understand me , of course i can add this class , but the div class when i scroll change to .affix  bot not change to .affix-bottom , so the div can`t read ur class !

Comment: try `#sideBarContainer.affix-bottom` as a selector with a higher specificity

Comment: :( i know what did you mean , but the Div not define with affix-bottom  when its be in the bottom !

Comment: Has you affixed element enough height? the .affix-bottom is the number of pixels from the bottom of your page. The bottom of the element you affix will scroll till this position.

Comment: Can you give me a example ?

Answer (score 0):

This will not work with the coma after the last element in a query

```
bottom: 200,
```

instead use

```
bottom: 200
```